# Access View Sizes from another class

Tags: android, view, size, fragment

I am getting view sizes by getBottom(), getRight() and using ViewTreeObserver it works fine. However the problem arises when I want to use these sizes for drawing Rectangle. For drawing I created **Rectangle class that extends View** but when I access **bottom** and **right** sizes from this class, **they return 0**.

How can I access the view sizes from another class?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to access its dimensions before even it gets drawn. Use this utility method I've created for my use:

https://gist.github.com/Saketme/d63daf0173c52c9dd930

The idea here is to wait until your View has been measured and drawn on the display. Polling its dimensions (left, bottom, width, height, etc.) before it happens (for example, inside the View's constructor or your Activity's `onCreate()`) will ***always*** return 0.

Comment: It's *okay* to use semaphores, but they aren't your best solution. Registering a listener as shown in my gist is possibly the best one.

Comment: I copied your code at the end of the code block but I do not know how to access it. I implemented view tree observer myself, but from class it is still 0